# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Japanese Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://japanese.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Let's get critical, critical - I wanna get critical - Let's get in to critical

Comment: @istrasci オリビアニュートンジョン？(ちょっと古い！w)

Comment: Does anyone have any comments on the questions or answers we reviewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

`Ex 　Sa　 NI　 sc`
　9　　3　　0　　9　　　[What is the yomikata of 値 in 破格値?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12540/1478)
　7　　3　　0　　7　　　[Is there any reference material for the origins of kanji on-yomi?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12555/1478)
　7　　2　　0　　7　　　[what is the logic for assigning Kanji characters to certain radicals?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12624/1478)
　7　　3　　1　　6　　　[What does にゃ mean at the end of a sentence or as a particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12534/1478)
　5　　5　　0　　5　　　[what does 何(+counter)+も+volitional mean? e.g. 何機も買おう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12549/1478)
　5　　5　　1　　4　　　[Similar example sentences give different meanings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12536/1478)
　5　　4　　1　　4　　　[Difference between ために and ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12450/1478)
　4　　5　　0　　4　　　[The で particle before です](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12457/1478)
　4　　5　　1　　3　　　[Is わくわく waku waku a feminine expression?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12428/1478) 
　3　　5　　0　　3　　　[Choice of さしあげる in お電話さしあげる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12584/1478)

`Ex` *Excellent*
`Sa` *Satisfactory*
`NI` *Needs Improvement*

`sc` ***Net Score***